# Plenoptic function meaning of dx

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to understand this paper on computer vision (http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/elements91.pdf) and it talks about building a periodic table of things we can get from the plenoptic function. It says that by taking the partial derivative of it with respect to x you can get "vertical
"edge"" but I have no idea what that is supposed to mean (page 13, top diagram). Does anyone understand that part?